How in depth does mishnayot for a neshama need to be
If you’re learning mishnayot לעילוי נשמה, how in depth does this learning have to be? Is simply reading through the mishnayot sufficient with no commentaries? Is it just until you understand pshat or is there something more to it? Further, can someone read through only the Hebrew without even understanding what they’re saying and that will be valid?
